# SocialEngine 4 - Followers/Following status display too long

Tags: socialengine

I have problem at columns Followers/Following which I put on the right side of my website and also on browse members page. The problems are:

1) when user post too long status its not displayed right on firefox

2) in cause of the long text follow/unfollow are displayed someone in the middle of the status

You can see what I mean by the added images.

What I suggest for a fix (but I don't know how to do it :() is this:

just remove status in this boxes (its not really needed to see last user status there)

or

limit the status characters

Also is there a way users can "clear" their status because I think it stays there until new one is posted, which is pretty stupid. Like if you post something which is ralated to something now but makes non sense in  the futre and then you dont post new status for like 10 days and someone sees it, it will look stupid.

thats the code

```
  <div class='profile_friends_body'>
        <div class='profile_friends_status'>
          <span>
            <?php echo $this->htmlLink($member->getHref(), $member->getTitle()) ?>
          </span>
          <?php echo $member->status; ?>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance and I think fix like that will be helpful to others too.

[image2](http://www.socialengineforum.com/uploads/monthly_04_2014/post-41713-0-32779600-1396311389.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove it from application/modeules/User/widgets/profile-friends-followers/index.tp

also its the same in profile-friends-followers and profile-friends

in the files I found this

```
<div class='profile_friends_body'>
        <div class='profile_friends_status'>
          <span>
            <?php echo $this->htmlLink($member->getHref(), $member->getTitle()) ?>
          </span>
          <?php echo $member->status; ?>
        </div>
```

and when you remove status; ?> then statuses are not shown anymore on this widgets, but I wanted just to limit the displayed characters and tried to use substr but couldn't manage to do it at the first time